# How to define zipWith by using zip and list comprehension

Tags: haskell, zip, list-comprehension, zipwith

I am trying to write zipWith function using zip and list comprehension. I need to zip the two lists after the function is applied. However I don't know where to use the list comprehension.

I tried doing two list comprehensions for each list.

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f xs ys = zip [f x | x <- xs] [f y | y <- ys]
```

I am expecting the function to be identical to zipWith, however it is not loading and giving error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        c ~ (b -> c, b -> c)
      Expected type: [c]
        Actual type: [(b -> c, b -> c)]
    • In the expression: zip [f x | x <- xs] [f y | y <- ys]
      In an equation for ‘zipWith'’:
          zipWith' f xs ys = zip [f x | x <- xs] [f y | y <- ys]

    • Relevant bindings include
        ys :: [b] (bound at tutorial5.hs:166:15)
        f :: a -> b -> c (bound at tutorial5.hs:166:10)
        zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
          (bound at tutorial5.hs:166:1)
    |
166 | zipWith' f xs ys = zip [f x | x <- xs] [f y | y <- ys]
```

Comment: Why would you want to implement `zipWith` (the more general function) using `zip` (the more specific)? `zip = zipWith (,)`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a few problems here. At the top level, think about the signature of `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]`: there's no way that it can return a `[c]` where `c` is not a tuple, so you don't want `zip` to be the outer function call in your new `zipWith`.  Your type error is arising from GHC noticing that it needs to force `c` to be a tuple of things with elements whose types contain `c` themselves (since `f` applied to anything will always have type `b -> c`).

Your list comprehensions are also basically the same thing as `map f xs` and `map f ys`.  The second of these can't typecheck, since each element of `ys` is a `b`, and you can't apply `f` to a `b` (its first argument is an `a`).

You instead could start by zipping the input lists to get `[(a,b)]`, and then using a list comprehension to run `f` on each pair:

```
zipWith' f xs ys = [f x y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys]
```

Or, with `map` and `uncurry` instead of a list comprehension:

```
zipWith' f xs ys = map (uncurry f) $ zip xs ys
```

Or, using the GHC parallel list comprehension extension (`-XParallelListComp`), explicitly designed to imitate `zip`:

```
zipWith' f xs ys = [f x y | x <- xs | y <- ys]
```

As mentioned above, you can't really do the `zip` *last*, since it'll produce tuples.  You could do something like

```
zipWith' f xs ys = [fx y | (fx, y) <- zip [f x | x <- xs] ys]
```

Which applies `f` to the elements of the first list (in `[f x | x <- xs]`, or alternatively `map f xs`), zips this list of partially applied functions with the list of second arguments, and then applies the partial functions to their corresponding second arguments in the outer comprehension, but it's a bit of a roundabout way to do this.